# Spring boot relationship is not initialized

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a entity called origin and wallet. in this scenario origin has a wallet. But when i run the code the origin values are coming but the wallet values are not coming.

```
package com.mobios.model;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "origin")
public class Origin {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "acc_no", nullable = false)
    private String acc_no;

    @Column(name = "mobile_number", nullable = true)
    private String mobile_number;


    @ManyToOne
    private Wallet wallet;


    public Wallet getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }

    public void setWallet(Wallet wallet) {
        this.wallet = wallet;
    }

}
```

Following is my DAO

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Origin authenticateOrigin(String _userName, int _pin) {
        Origin _origin;
        String _query = "SELECT * FROM origin WHERE mobile_number= ? and pin= ?";
        _origin = (Origin) _jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(_query, new Object[] 
     { _userName, _pin },
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Origin.class));

        return _origin;
     }
```

I cant find where i have done wrong.

I have edited my interface as follows

```
public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<Origin, String>{

/**
 * Return the authenticated origin. If not will return null
 * 
 * @return _origin
 */

Origin authenticateOrigin(String _userName, int _pin);

}
```

But i cannot understand how to call the query in this case. JPA generate some methods to get data from database. i dont need it. I need to get data by using customized queries

Comment: Well, you're using SQL, completely bypassing the JPA EntityManager, to load only the origin columns. Why would the wallet be populated? Use a JPQL query, using the JPA API. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Can you explain how to overcome this problem @JBNizet

Comment: I have already. Use the JPA API (EntityManager) to execute a JPQL query. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-. In a Spring world, you would typically use a Spring-data-jpa repository, with a method with a well-defined name (where the query would automatically be inferred fromt the method name), or annotated with `@Query` to specify the JPQL query. If you have no idea of what I am talking about, then it means you have to start learning how JPA works before using it.

Comment: I have referred but i cannot use those methods to fix my problem. Can you give solution to fix this please @JBNizet

Comment: Edit your question, and show what you have tried. 1 hour is very short to learn JPA.

Comment: Have edited @JBNizet

Comment: 1. Respect the Java naming conventions. This is critical. 2. Write a method with the right name (findByAccNoAndMobileNumber), or choose any name you want but annotate it with `@Query("the jpql query")`. All this is explained in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: No. I won't do that.

Comment: Ok sorry for asking. The data are coming except the related table. @JBNizet

Comment: I can't tell you why your code doesn't work correctly if you don't post your code. If you haven't changed your code and are still using SQL, see my first comment.